# Listview checkbox selecting all/Deslecting all C# 4.0

Tags: c#-4.0

I have listview and i have checkboxes enabled in the listview How would i check all the checkboxes in the listview and deselect?

Thank you

Comment: XNA? WinForms? ASP.Net? Silverlight? WPF? MonoTouch?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this will help you:

```
if (chkSelectAll.IsChecked == true) {
    for (int y = listitem.Items.Count - 1; y >= 0; y--) {
        System.Windows.Controls.CheckBox chk= (System.Windows.Controls.CheckBox)listitem.Items[y];
        chk.IsChecked = true;
    }
}
```

This code goes inside your event.

Answer (score 2):

You should loop through the `Items` collection and set the `Checked` property for each one.

Comment: so a foreach loop checked property to true?

Comment: `int listCount = listView1.Items.Count;



            foreach (ListViewItem item in listView1.Items)
            {

                item.Checked = true; 
            }

            itemsChecked.Text = listCount.ToString();`