# How to Add a Checkbox to a List View Column Header in c# Winform App?

Tags: c#, winforms, listview, checkbox

[image]

I want to add checkbox in header and also if I checked in header checkbox it should be like select all and deselect All... just like above image!

[image]

I want to create this type of listview header with checkbox in c#

Comment: have you seen this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5554068/listview-checkbox-selecting-all-deslecting-all-c-sharp-4-0?answertab=votes#tab-top) ?

Comment: @Robotnik look at the above image i want to add checkbox to listview header

Comment: You can set `OwnerDraw` property of `ListView` to true and draw a `ChceckBox` on first column header and handle `ColumnClick` to perform select/deselect all.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can set [`OwnerDraw`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.listview.ownerdraw?WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235&view=netframework-4.8) property of `ListView` to true and draw a `ChceckBox` on first column header and handle `ColumnClick` to perform select/deselect all.

- For drawing the `ListView` you need to handle `DrawColumnHeader`, `DrawItem` and `DrawSubItem` events.
- Draw checkbox in `DrawColumnHeader` event.
- Set `e.DrawDefault = true;` for other drawing events to draw default rendering.
- Handle `ColumnClick` event and store the checked state of column header in tag of column. Also for each item of list view, set `Checked` property to perform select/deselect all.

**Code:**

```
private void listView1_DrawColumnHeader(object sender, 
                                        DrawListViewColumnHeaderEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.ColumnIndex == 0)
    {
        e.DrawBackground();
        bool value = false;
        try
        {
            value = Convert.ToBoolean(e.Header.Tag);
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
        }
        CheckBoxRenderer.DrawCheckBox(e.Graphics, 
            new Point(e.Bounds.Left + 4, e.Bounds.Top + 4),
            value ? System.Windows.Forms.VisualStyles.CheckBoxState.CheckedNormal :
            System.Windows.Forms.VisualStyles.CheckBoxState.UncheckedNormal);
    }
    else
    {
        e.DrawDefault = true;
    }
}

private void listView1_DrawItem(object sender, DrawListViewItemEventArgs e)
{
    e.DrawDefault = true;
}

private void listView1_DrawSubItem(object sender, DrawListViewSubItemEventArgs e)
{
    e.DrawDefault = true;
}

private void listView1_ColumnClick(object sender, ColumnClickEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Column == 0)
    {
        bool value = false;
        try
        {
            value = Convert.ToBoolean(this.listView1.Columns[e.Column].Tag);
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
        }
        this.listView1.Columns[e.Column].Tag = !value;
        foreach (ListViewItem item in this.listView1.Items)
            item.Checked = !value;

        this.listView1.Invalidate();
    }
}
```

**Screenshot:**

[image]

- In the above image I have 3 columns.
- I set empty text for first column.
- I Set `CheckBoxes` property of `ListView` to true.
- I Set empty text for items and added 2 sub items for each item.

Comment: @SantoshKokatnur you could have given some credit to Reza Aghaei in your codeproject article...
https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/1083589/Adding-Checkbox-to-a-List-View-Column-Header-in-Cs

Comment: @Dom84 have given credit to Reza in codeproject. Have a look.