# How to make one checkbox make all checboxes checked in Listview C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio, winforms

I am making quarantine and I have `listView` for showcase of all viruses, and I added checkbox to listview in Header Column (I don't know if I can add checkbox in header column). I added separate column with checkboxes.

I want that checkbox in header when it's checked that all checkboxes in viewlist items are checked.

I hope somebody can help. Thanks!

Comment: Hook the OnClick or Changed event of the checkbox, and loop through the listview items, setting the checkbox in each item to checked.

Comment: [How to Add a Checkbox to a List View Column Header in c# Winform App?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35790015/3110834)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using a Button Click:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{ 
   for (int i = 0; i < listView1.Items.Count; i++)
  {
    listView1.Items[i].Checked = true;
  }
}
```

Clicking on the Column Header you can use the `listView1_ColumnClick(object sender, ColumnClickEventArgs e)` event.

Answer (score 3):

In case you have a separate "Select All" checkbox for selecting all items you can have code like:

```
private void cbSelectAll_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    foreach (ListViewItem listViewItem in listView.Items)
    {
        listViewItem.Checked = cbSelectAll.Checked;
    }
}
```

If you want to check all items by clicking on any of list view item, then you have to subscribe to `ItemChecked` event of a list view:

```
private void listView_ItemChecked(object sender, ItemCheckedEventArgs e)
{
    foreach (ListViewItem listViewItem in listView.Items)
    {
        listViewItem.Checked = e.Item.Checked;
    }
}
```

PS: To display checkbox above list items set the `CheckBoxes` flag to `true`