# How do I fix control ghosting issue in ListView?

Tags: c#, vb.net, winforms, listview, windows-forms-designer

I have a ListView control and I want to add a checkbox in upper left corner of ListView.

The solution for adding the CheckBox control that I'm using is this:

```
Me.ListViewCustom1.Controls.Add(CheckBoxControl);
Me.CheckBoxControl.Location = new Point(3, 5);
```

The issue I'm having is on ListView scroll. The checkbox appears all smeared up. I've been scavaging the web for a solution and I really can't find something that would solve this issue.

This is how the controls appears:

[image: Image(Sorry for random data)]

I hereby asking for help in this complicated situation.

Comment: [How to add a Checkbox to a ListView column header?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35790015/3110834)

Comment: I actually saw that post. The idea with adding a dedicated column for the checkbox is clever but I would like to solve the issue without the new column. Do you think it's possible?

Comment: [See here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1851620/handling-scroll-event-on-listview-in-c-sharp) on capturing the scroll event ; then maybe a refresh will help..

Comment: I've had problems with this solution aswell. Because the position I set doesn't follow the "column". The checkbox, after refresh, appears in position not relative to first column :/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you don't want the option that I used in the [linked post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35790015/3110834), the other way that you can approach this is adding the `CheckBox` to the header of the `ListView`.

Using [SendMessage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-sendmessage?WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235)You can send [LVM_GETHEADER](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/lvm-getheader?WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235) message to the listview control and get the handle of the header, then [SetParent](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-setparent?WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235) will help you to set the header as parent of checkbox:

```
const int LVM_GETHEADER = 0x1000 + 31;
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
static extern IntPtr SendMessage(IntPtr hWnd, int Msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam);
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
static extern IntPtr SetParent(IntPtr hWndChild, IntPtr hWndNewParent);
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var header = SendMessage(listView1.Handle, LVM_GETHEADER, IntPtr.Zero, IntPtr.Zero);
    var checkBox = new CheckBox()
    {
        AutoSize = true,
        Text = "",
        Location = new Point(3, 5)
    };
    this.listView1.Controls.Add(checkBox);
    SetParent(checkBox.Handle, header);
}
```

And this is what you get:

[image]

Obviously I've added a few extra spaces before text of the column header to make room for the check box.

Comment: This looks promissing! I'll take a look at that as soon as I can and I'll mark your answer as the correct one afterwards. Thank you :)

Comment: I've tested the answer. Checkbox appears but is instantly hidden after hovering mouse on first column.

Comment: @PashaZakharuk It works properly in my tests. You probably have mixed your own solution with this post. Look at the updated screen capture.

Comment: You're right. I'm considering your answer as the correct one. I've created a brand new control and it works perfectly! Thank you!

Comment: Cool! My pleasure :)