# How to check all checkbox by pressing one?

Tags: c#, winforms, checkbox

I want to make a code by selecting a checkbox from the ListView to automatically select all the checkbox from the ListView.

I'm using visual studio 2005 so I don't have ItemChecked form.
Thats why I want to make this by using ListView itemcheck event. Here is my code.

[image]

```
private void lvBase_ItemCheck_1(object sender, ItemCheckEventArgs e)
{

    if ( ) // If selecting one checkbox from the ListView
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < lvBase.Items.Count; i++)
        {
         // Select all checkbox from the ListView
         }
     }
     else // If unselecting one checkbox from the ListView
     {
        for (int i = 0; i < lvBase.Items.Count; i++)
        {
         // Unselect all checkbox from the ListView
         }
     } 
}
```

Can you help me to fill this out? Or if you have any better idea please share :)

Comment: You should loop through the Items collection and set the Checked property for each one.

Comment: Thanks for your response! I'm not good at C# but do you mean "lvBase.Items[i].Checked == true"? and I don't know what to fill out in the "if".. Can you help me?

Comment: that's a different question.  have a look at the listview properties for a checkAll or something - sorry not sure myself

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note: there's most likely a better way to do this, but this is a pattern I used a long time ago and it worked then. :)

In the event you've shown above, it will be called from the listView, and the `ItemCheckEventArgs e` will tell you if the box is checked or not. It actually tells you the state of the checkbox *before* the check. So if checkbox was unchecked and the user just checked it, `e.CurrentValue` will be `CheckState.Unchecked`.

Now, the problem we may have if we try to update the state of all the checkboxes inside the `ItemCheck` event is that we will recursively call the event each time we check a box. One way around this is to track whether or not the user is calling the event (by checking a box) or we're triggering the event by calling `item.Checked = true;`.

Something like this may do the trick:

```
// Set this to true when our code is modifying the checked state of a listbox item
private bool changingCheckboxState = false;

private void lvBase_ItemCheck(object sender, ItemCheckEventArgs e)
{
    // If our code triggered this event, just return right away
    if (changingCheckboxState) return;

    // Set our flag so that calls to this method inside the 
    // loop below don't trigger more calls to this method
    changingCheckboxState = true;

    // Set all the checkboxes to match the state of this one
    foreach(ListViewItem item in lvBase.Items)
    {
        item.Checked = e.CurrentValue != CheckState.Checked;
    }

    // Now that we're done, set our flag to false again
    changingCheckboxState = false;
}
```

Comment: It works!! Thank you for sharing your knowledge Rufus L :)

Answer (score 1):

Use the [`ListViewItem.Selected`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listviewitem.selected.aspx) property:

```
foreach(ListViewItem item in lv.Items)
    item.Selected = true;


foreach(ListViewItem item in lv.Items)
    item.Selected = !item.Selected;
```

Comment: Do you mean to erase the If-else and paste your code? It doesn't work :(

Comment: have a look at this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5554068/listview-checkbox-selecting-all-deslecting-all-c-sharp-4-0

Comment: i'm showing the setting of the Checked property.  It's unclear to me how or what is used to say whether the user wants to select-all or deselect-all from your code.

Comment: Can you tell me how to get the ListView checkbox selecting code to fill in the "If()"

Comment: updated my answer for you - if happy please click the `tick` to mark as answered - thanks

Comment: Sorry for asking much. Can you please give me the full code starting from the "private void...."? I'm not good at coding..